C++/fmt - fmt::v7::format_error::~format_error() was replaced
This works:
#include "fmt/core.h"
#include "fmt/color.h"

void displayHelp() {
    fmt::print("Help!");
}

but this:
#include "fmt/core.h"
#include "fmt/color.h"

void displayHelp() {
    fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::orange) | fmt::emphasis::bold,"Help!");
}

Gives the following error:
[ 94%] Built target Vibranium-Engine
[ 94%] Building CXX object dep/Vibranium-Engine/Vibranium/CMakeFiles/vibranium.dir/Vibranium.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable V:\Vibranium-Core\vibranium.exe
ld.lld: error: fmt::v7::format_error::~format_error() was replaced
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
mingw32-make[3]: *** [dep\Vibranium-Engine\Vibranium\CMakeFiles\vibranium.dir\build.make:263: V:/Vibranium-Core/vibranium.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1957: dep/Vibranium-Engine/Vibranium/CMakeFiles/vibranium.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1964: dep/Vibranium-Engine/Vibranium/CMakeFiles/vibranium.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:766: vibranium] Error 2

Any idea why is that and how can I fix it ?
This code runs well on MacOS and Linux, but on Windows with MinGW looks like I can't build.

What is your version of fmt? Seems to work: https://godbolt.org/z/zM7bjxPxW with fmt 10.2

Sadly godbolt do not like fmt on Windows: https://godbolt.org/z/9fxYbvjW6
